# RibbonLib will not build, exits with code 3 (can't find the file)

Tags: c#, compilation

I am trying to compile this Ribbon Libray (http://windowsribbon.codeplex.com/) but it says there are some files missing, which I have then gone to in explorer and they are indeed missing, and I have no idea why (I haven't removed any files).

> Error 1   The command
>   ""%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\UICC.exe"
>   "C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\RibbonLib_v1.0\Samples\01-AddingRibbonSupport\RibbonMarkup.xml" "**C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\RibbonLib_v1.0\Samples\01-AddingRibbonSupport\RibbonMarkup.bml**" /header:"**C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\RibbonLib_v1.0\Samples\01-AddingRibbonSupport\RibbonMarkupIds.h**"
>   /res:"**C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\RibbonLib_v1.0\Samples\01-AddingRibbonSupport\RibbonMarkup.rc**"
>   "%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\rc.exe" /r
>   "C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\RibbonLib_v1.0\Samples\01-AddingRibbonSupport\RibbonMarkup.rc"
>   " exited with code
>   3.    01-AddingRibbonSupport

So I went to C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\RibbonLib_v1.0\Samples\01-AddingRibbonSupport\
and the files in bold above are not there (they end in .bml .h and .rc) So where do I get these files from???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, it looks too complicated, this is really annoying me, all I want is a free Ribbon UI in **VB NET** NOT C#

I've tried this one: http://www.menendezpoo.com/a.php?h=a4905e870cd806
But I can't get the stupid thing to be Aero at the top, as it is in the first image in the page, it says I need to extend the Aero into the Non-Client Area, which I can do expect it loses the forms' title and the close/maximize/minimize button. And the examples he gives all in C# which don't work in VB, and are too vague.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try to re-install it and then test by creating a new test solution?, maybe this can solve your problem with the Ribbon Bar library.

Comment: re install what? VS studio, W7 SDK? Or the Ribbon Lib, becase you don't install that and I have just downloaded it.